# Cant upgrade libraries using pip

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to upgrade matplotlib using pip install matplotlib --upgrade I get the following

"setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution"

setuptools is installed and up to date, so I'm lost.

EDIT:
If this adds any context, it started happening after I upgraded distribute

EDIT:
I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling setuptools

Comment: what version of pip are you using?

Comment: Try `pip install setuptools --upgrade`

Comment: try this  :                                                                                                     curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python , if curl not present , follow this link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: It says setuptools is up to date Im using pip 7.0.3. Whenever I try to install any library I get that message as well.

Comment: my guess is because you have a different version python running, what version of python are you using

Comment: Im using python 2.6.

Comment: well I guess here is whats happening, each version of Python requires its own copy of setuptools, so if you manually installed python, try to reinstall the setuptools for that python version

Comment: how did you install pip?

Comment: try running this command :  pip --version, it should show you the site packages info,